# Using Pivot in SQL server with two columns as primary key

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table like this, I use `code1` and `code2` as a primary key.

```
Code1   Code2  Data1 Data2 Data3
 11       0      a     b     7
 11       1      b     b     6 
 12       2      z     v     5
```

I would like to transform the table into this :

```
Code1    Code2   TheData  (create id ?)
 11        0       a         0
 11        0       b         1
 11        0       7         2
 11        1       b         0
 11        1       b         1
 11        1       6         2
 12        2       z         0
 12        2       v         1
 12        2       5         2
```

I thought about adding an id because I'm losing the information of which data I've inserted.

Later in the SQl I'll use the id to retrieve the good data but it is not the question here.
The number of column in 'temp' is static so I can pivot as I like.

Comment: What happened to 1?

Comment: I forget it, editing right away !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an UNPIVOT is cleaner and more efficient, make sure to cast the value in the column format.

```
SELECT Code1, Code2, Value, Idname
FROM
(SELECT Code1, Code2,
CAST (Data1 AS varchar) AS Data1, 
    CAST (Data2 AS varchar) AS Data2, CAST (Data3 AS varchar) AS Data3
 FROM @table
) temp
UNPIVOT
(
Value FOR Idname IN (Data1, 
    Data2, Data3)
) as Result
```

Comment: `UNPIVOT` is not a MySQL operation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't checked the automated tags

Answer (score 3):

You can use `union all`:

```
select code1, code2, data1 as thedata, 0 as new_id from temp
union all
select code1, code2, data2 as thedata, 1 from temp
union all
select code1, code2, data3 as thedata, 2 from temp;
```

If you actually want the results in the order you have specified, use `order by 1, 2, 4`.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you did. I'll try this but isn't using pivot would have been more efficient ? I've never used pivot and wanted to use it this time.

Comment: @Benoît There is no such thing.

Comment: Oh, ok. It is because my temp table is the 'history n-1' of another one which contains the most recent values n. I need after that to insert the rows of n-1 in table n. I thought PIVOT would have helped, but I guess you are right. Thanks